# Limit number of JQuery appends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a userscript that adds a button to a specific stie, but I have encountered a problem that I'm not able to solve at my level of competence.

So in order to add the button I use JQuery, but the problem is that the element I'm appending it to does not hold a specific ID, which makes locating only the wanted element hard using JQuery.

I'm currently doing this:

```
$("div:contains('Add line')")
```

This works in the sense that my button is added at the place where I want it, but here's the problem that comes out of this: this also appends my button at other places on the site where I don't want it. So my question is if I'm able to limit the times that JQuery appends my button. The correct button is added first of them all so ideally I would just like to tell jquery to append my button once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the very first element that matches your selector by using the `.first()` method right after your selector. Like this:

```
$("div:contains('Add line')").first()
```

Comment: And if it's always at another specific index use `eq()`

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on what @martin said you can iterate over what jQuery returns and only pick the dom node you want to append to.

However, the main issue here is that the button could change the it's order in the dom, so you're going to have broken code.

Since you're mentioning a single button, isn't there a more unique identifier / css path / x-path that you can use to pinpoint that div ?